# Ocultar menu na tela de login C#

Tags: c#, html5, .net, asp.net

Estou com um probleminha, preciso ocultar um menu na tela de login quando ela é carregada. Utilizei uma solução que funciona local, mas no server não acontece, segue abaixo:

```
//MENU QUE FICA NA MASTER PAGE
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                      //CONTEUDO DO MENU
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                 </asp:LoginView>
 </asp:Panel>

//ISSO ESTÁ NO PAGE_LOAD DA TELA DE LOGIN
Panel ocultaMenu = (Panel)Master.FindControl("Panel1");
ocultaMenu.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Gostaria de saber, em qual arquivo você colocou essa configuração ai?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar alterar a propriedade do elemento(Design), e de acordo que for feito o login fazer alteração no codigo. Em propriedade vá em Behavior, encontre a opção Enabled e coloca false. no codigo onde quer carregar coloca Panel1.Enabled = true;

Comment: <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Enabled="False">

Não entendi muito bem, mas se era pra fazer isso também não deu certo

Answer (score 0):

Testei seu código aqui e funciona normalmente, mas como não está funcionando no servidor não custa nada verificar outras possibilidades.

Você pode criar um método na Master.cs que recebe true ou false, neste método você exibe ou esconde o componente.

```
public partial class MyMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void EsconderExibirPanel(bool exibe)
    {
        Panel1.Visible = exibe;
    }
}
```

E onde você quer esconder o componente pode invocar esse método.

```
((MyMaster)Page.Master).EsconderExibirPanel(false);
```

Comment: Então eu cheguei a fazer essa tentativa também e mesmo assim no servidor não estava funcionando. Por fim descobri o problema, eu estava subindo apenas as partes de código que alterei, quando enviei o projeto por inteiro deu certo. Valeu pela força man!

Comment: Tranquilo, o Importante que deu certo!